# Closing and opening <p> tags

Tags: php, domdocument

I have a function that wraps `<img>` tags in a `<div>`. Often these can appear in `<p>` tags (due to a wysiwyg editor).

```
    $doc->loadHtml($str);

    $tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');

    foreach ($tags as $tag) {

        $div = $doc->createElement('div');
        $tag->parentNode->insertBefore($div, $tag);
        $div->appendChild($tag);
    }
```

I want to change my function so that if there is an open `<p>` tag, it appends a closing `</p>` tag before the opening `<div>`, and then adds an opening `<p>` after the closing `</div>`.

Currently when input is

```
'<p>blah blah <img src="incorrect.gif"> blah blah</p>
```

My output is

```
'<p>blah blah <div><img src="incorrect.gif"></div> blah blah</p>
```

I want output to be

```
'<p>blah blah </p><div><img src="correct.gif"></div><p> blah blah</p>
```

Comment: $html ='<p>blah blah <div><img src="incorrect.gif"></div> blah blah</p>';
echo preg_replace("/<p>(.*?)<div>(.*?)<\/div>(.*?)<\/p>/", "<p>$1</p><div>$2</div><p>$3</p>", $html);

Comment: echo preg_replace("/<p>(.*?)<div>(.*?)<\/div>(.*?)<\/p>/", "<p>$1</p><div>$2</div><p>$3</p>", $html);

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches coming to my mind:

1. instead of wrapping images with `<div>...</div>`, wrap them with `</p><div>...</div><p>`
2. detect the div tags and wrap them with `</p>...<p>`

---

If you are certain that the wrapping you use around images is *always* a `<div>...</div>` pair, you might consider using regex to do a simple replace:

**PHP**

`$html = preg_replace_all('/<div[^>]*>(.*?)</div>/i', '</p>$1<p>', $html)`

This will also work if you include attributes in your wrapping `div` elements. However, if you intend on starting to use regex for more complex operations on HTML, here is a previous post that details why it is a bad idea:

> [Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **preg_replace** function to achieve this.

```
$html ='<p>blah blah <div><img src="incorrect.gif"></div> blah blah</p>';
echo preg_replace("/<p>(.*?)<div>(.*?)<\/div>(.*?)<\/p>/", "<p>$1</p><div>$2</div><p>$3</p>", $html);
```

I have tested couple of case although check using couple others